# Random variables are independent iff transition probability is independent from first result $x$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I try to figure out why two real-valued random variables $X,Y$ (defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$) are independent iff for all $B_1 \in \mathcal B^1$ the probability $P_1^2(x,B)$ is independent of $x$ ($\lambda$ almost everywhere)

(under the assumptions that $P_1$ is probability measure on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B^1)$ with positive $\lambda$-density, $P_1^2$ is Markov kernel from $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B^1)$ to $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B^1)$ and $P^{(X,Y)} = P_1 \otimes P_1^2$ (where this $\otimes$ does not mean the usual product measure).)

A hint says it's easy to check by computing $P^X, P^Y$ first (is this $P^X(A) = P^{(X,Y)}(A \times \mathbb R)$?) and by using the fact that if the Lebesgue integral over a function is 0, then the function is 0 ($\lambda$ almost everywhere). I'm confused how this should help.

Can someone explain?